# How binding and rendering observable properties in blazor?

Tags: c#, properties, binding, blazor, observable

I Investigate Blazor and attempting binding observable property to Sf Progress Bar.  Property looks like following and created in backend lib.

```
    public long Counter
    {
        get => _counterSubject.Value;
        set => _counterSubject.OnNext(value);
    }
    public IObservable<long> CounterState => _counterSubject;
```

This property changes when method load data.

In service that injected to blazor page this property init another not observable property.

```
public long Counter { get; set; } = 0;

//some code

public async Task<long> GetAsync(OemCatalogRequest request)
{
    Counter = _someService.Counter;
}
```

The part of the Blazor page with property binding to progress bar looks like:

```
    <SfProgressBar Value="@FetchService.Counter" IsActive="@_loadingFlag" Minimum="0" Maximum="@FetchService.TotalCount" TrackThickness="12" ProgressThickness="12">
        <ProgressBarAnimation Enable="@_loadingFlag"></ProgressBarAnimation>
    </SfProgressBar>

<h2>Tonal count: @FetchService.TotalCount</h2>
<h2>Counter: @FetchService.Counter</h2>
```

On Debug i see that @FetchService.Counter chaneged but not rendering on blazor page. And progress bar changing when data loading completed.
I new in Blazor. What i doing wring?